# Find the domain of derivative of the function $f(x)=\mid \sin^{-1}(2x^2-1)\mid$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Find the domain of derivative of the function $f(x)=\mid \sin^{-1}(2x^2-1)\mid$.

I was a little confused about the modulus. I can do the derivative and even calculate the domain, but, the modulus is creating the confusion. Please help.

I was also confused about one more thing. Is differentiation allowed in complex numbers? If so, then are the $i$-s treated as constants?

Thank you.

Comment: but the function is not derivable each $x$ of the given range

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$ f(x)=\left|arcsin(2x^2-1)\right|=\left|arcsin(1-2x^2)\right|=\sqrt{\arcsin^2(1-2x^2)} $$